# how to display .txt file in jtext area in netbeans7.0

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I created the textarea on the form on which I am working but don't know how to display the contents of text file in jtextArea in netbeans7.0

Answer (score 3):

I saw this suggestion on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea) earlier: Use the [read()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read%28java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.Object%29) method of JTextComponent.

```
    textArea.read(new FileReader(textFile), "here's a description of the file");
```

Comment: +1, it still amazes me that people don't know about the read(..) method and keep reinventing the wheel. Thanks for spreading the word.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Netbeans 7.0. In Java this is how you set text to a `JTextArea`:

```
jTextAreaInstance.setText("myText");
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i want to display the whole multiline text file in textarea. any suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have a JTextArea, just call `setText(String yourText)` to populate it.

Also see the tutorial: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html