# How to edit SQL files using Java?

Tags: java, sql

I need to edit .sql files with Java, so that I can set all the options before sending the sql to a server.

I have an exported SQL, from one of my servers, but need to change some of its contents before sending it back to another server, importing it.

I have, for example, a mail variable, that I need to switch the mail option for inside the SQL

I couldn't find any way to edit the file contents programatically, without having to send it to a server.
Is it actually possible to edit an SQL file using only Java, and not a SQL server?

Is there a way to do it?

@EDIT

As stated in the comments, an SQL file is just a .txt file.

Knowing that, I needed a way to change the database lines and columns using java, programmatically.

The reason for that is that I'm creating multiple websites, and their information is stored inside an SQL. I wanted to quickly edit each site's info inside the SQL file, so that it would be easier to upload to the host.

Comment: ".SQL" files are just text files.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do, and show your existing code? If you're trying to run queries against an SQL server, you should be using JDBC.

Comment: @deyur I have an exported SQL file, from one of my servers, but need to change some of its contents before sending it back to another server, importing it.

Comment: Related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea

Comment: I need to change some values inside the SQL for some I have in variables

Comment: If you need to "change some of its content", you can do it by "writing some code". Vague requirements -> vague solutions.

Comment: @JBNizet And what kind of code can I write to send statements to a SQL file?

Comment: @Kerooker Add sample SQL file to question, and we *might* be able to answer you.

Comment: You don't send statements to a SQL file. You write text to a file, and this text happens to be SQL. Ask a clear, detailed question. We have no idea what your source file looks like.

Comment: @deyur I editted the question to include an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried to include more requirements and what I tried to do, do you think it's any better?

Comment: @Andreas I tried to add some sample and examples of what I'm trying to accomplish. Do you think it's enough?

Comment: @Kerooker **DO NOT** replace a question with totally different text. Especially since you already accepted an answer two years ago. Rolling back your changes!!! Create a new question.

Comment: @andreas Help Center told me to edit and improve all my bad questions so my question ban can be lifted. What can I do about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just read the text from your SQL file in a String, then replace the content you need to replace before writing back into the SQL file.

This of course works for any type of text file, not only SQL. Like someone said in comment, SQL files are just text files