# Java: How to show the content of a file, opened by JFileChooser, in a JTextField?

Tags: java, file, user-interface, jtextfield, jfilechooser

I'm starting to learn Java and don't know how to show the content of a given file, that is opened by JFileChooser, in a JTextField

This is my code so far.

I deleted some imports and code for the better understanding of my program.

```
public class Afvink6 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private JLabel bestandnaam;
private JTextField bestand;
private JButton blader;
private JButton analyseer;
private JLabel informatie;
private JTextArea textarea;
private JLabel naampercentage;
private JPanel percentages;
private PrintWriter outFile;
private JFileChooser fileChooser;
private int reply;




@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == blader){
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        reply = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (reply == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            bestand.setText(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    if(event.getSource() ==analyseer){
```

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: A file usually contains more that one line. A JTextField is not the best component to display multiplelines of text. You'd better use a JTextArea. Anyway: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read-java.io.Reader-java.lang.Object-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Answer (score 1):

File.getAbsolutePath() only returns the pathname. You're going to need to setText as the actual content of the file.

You can do this in a variety of ways. Here is one:

```
java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(selectedFile.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

for example, will return a List that you can join all together and setText on the JTextField to display all the content.

Suggestion: you might want to use a TextArea (shows multiple lines) instead. See: [Loading a text file into a text area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea)