# JTextArea does not appear on JPanel with null layout

Tags: java, swing, file, jtextarea

How can I make my JTextArea show up? All of the functionality of the class works when it is callef from another class with a constructor that takes a file, and I can get the text perfectly from the JTextArea with getText() after setting the text for it to the text of the file, however, the JTextArea doesn't show up at all on the panel, even though I am adding it and setting a size and location.

I know the problem is with the text area itself and not the file so I tried changing the layout which is what I read on a similar aquestion, however, it did not work.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class EditableArea extends JPanel
{
JTextArea text;

public EditableArea()
{
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    text = new JTextArea(5, 20);
    text.setText("default text");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(text);
    add(scrollPane);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text.setSize(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
```

By default Swing components have a size of (0, 0).

The panel has not been added to visible GUI so the size of the panel is (0, 0) so the size of the text is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.

Don't attempt to set the size of the text area. Swing component should determine their own preferred size and a layout manager should be used so the component is displayed at its preferred size.

So the basic code should be:

```
//setLayout(null);
text = new JTextArea(5, 20);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
add( scrollPane );
// add text from file to the text area.
```

The above logic will:

1. specify the default row/columns of the text area.
2. add the text area to a scroll pane in case the text file contains more than 5 rows of data so you can scroll the text in the text area.

Also, when you read the file into the text area you should just use the `read(..)` method of the text area to read the file. Don't reinvent the wheel.

See: [Loading a text file into a textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380) for a simple example that incorporates all the above suggestions.

Comment: @carnickr I modified my class to fit your code, but the text still does not show up.

Comment: @ I can't possibly what you are doing or what you changed. Basically the entire code you posted is wrong, so you need to start over. I provided you with a complete working example. Did you test that code? Use that code as the starting point and customize it for your specific requirements.

Comment: sorry fro the lack of clarity. I edited the code that I posted on the original question so that it matched your code and put it in a JFrame to see if it would show up. The background does show up but the text area does not is what I meant. The new code is the entirety of the class I tested.

Comment: I was able to redo it and figure it out. Thanks for your help.