# Can't read txt file as a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to write  piece of code that displays the contents of a txt file as a JTextArea when the user clicks the button. The code I wrote is down below but when I click the button it doesn't show anything.

```
if(e.getSource() == showAttendanceList_sbm){
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
    try (Reader myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("mytextfile.txt"))) {
        textArea.read(myReader, "File");
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the if block is entered? Have you tested this?  Do any exceptions get thrown? Is the file located within a Jar file? Is your path to the file is correct relative to the user's home directory? Are you sure -- have you tested this?

Comment: You create your JTextArea, `JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);`, but don't show that you have put it into the GUI. This code becomes meaningless in this situation since you're not using a JTextArea that is displayed within the GUI. Please show a valid [mre] and ask a complete question

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes I have tested it, there is no exceptions. And the path is correct before this, I have tried some other method and it printed the txt file contents to the console. But now with this code, when I click the button it doesn't show anything.

Comment: Again, why should it show anything if the JTextArea that is reading the text is not displayed?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "implement it outside". The plain fact of the matter is that a non-displayed JTextArea won't help you much, but this is nothing more than common sense, no?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380 for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work because you appear to be reading the text into a non-displayed component, a JTextArea that is nowhere to be seen.

If you want this code to work, the JTextArea should already be in the GUI from the start, and you should read with this *displayed* JTextArea. If you desire to add the JTextArea into the GUI after reading the file, then you need to write code that will do this for you, best done with a CardLayout that swaps views for you.

Note that it is also usually better to get the text as a resource and not as a file, especially if you plan to package the text within the jar file. It's also a lot easier to change the state of components that are already present in the GUI than to add components during the run of the GUI, but the latter is not impossible, just more difficult.