# need help reading a file and displaying contents on a jpanel using setText()

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, filereader

on netbeans, im trying to read a file and display its contents on a swing graphics tab. This is how im reading the file

```
    FileReader reader;
    ArrayList<String> file = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner scan = null;
    try 
    {
        reader = new FileReader(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(reader);
        
        
        while(scan.hasNext())
        {
            file.add(scan.nextLine());
        }

        return file;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        scan.close();
    }

    return null;
```

This is how I'm writing the file

```
public String writeFile(ArrayList<String> data)
{
    String writer = "";
    for (String line : data)
    {
        writer += (line + lineSeparator);
    }
    return writer;
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to display it

```
FileIO file = new FileIO();
    String filePath="squeeze.txt";
    ArrayList<String> data = file.readFile(filePath);
    jTextField1.setText(file.writeFile(data));
```

And I getting an error on

```
scan.close();
```

Comment: What if `reader = new FileReader(filename);` fails? Try checking if `scan` is null before you attempt to close it.

Comment: That is not how I would read the file into a Swing component. I would no use a JTextField since it is designed to only display a single line of text. I would use a JTextArea. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380 for a working example of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that `scan` has not been initialized prior to the try block.  Anything in the try block might throw an exception, so therefore you have to write your code assuming that all code in the try block will never be run.  Luckily, Java has a syntax just for this situation called try-with-resources.  Try-with-resources handles your resources for you, and automatically closes them at the end of the try block.  Here is your code, modified to use try-with-resources:

```
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(filename);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(reader)) {
    while(scan.hasNext()) {
        file.add(scan.nextLine());
    }

    return file;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
```

I also notice that in your catch block, you simply print the stack trace.  This is perfectly fine as far as syntax goes, and the compiler will accept it, but I wouldn't recommend swallowing errors like this.  If you don't want to do anything special, the best all-purpose line you can use is `throw new RuntimeException();`.  This just throws a generic runtime exception, which will print the stack trace and then terminate the program.  This also has the added benefit that you don't need the `return null;` line at the bottom, since the runtime exception will exit the program anyway, and then any method that calls this method can safely assume that this method returns a non-null value.

Answer (score 0):

```
jTextField1.setText(file.writeFile(data));
```

A `JTextField` is for single lines of text. For multiple lines, use a [**`JTextArea`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

As to the problem at hand, the easiest solution is to use methods available to any `JTextComponent` (which includes both of the above).

Namely [`JTextComponent.read(Reader,Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#read(java.io.Reader,java.lang.Object)) & [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write(java.io.Writer)).