# Why isn't my output being saved as a file?

Tags: java, swing, io, text-files

I am creating an application that takes in user input, sends it to my pccalc method and when the submit button in the GUI class (not present) is pressed opens the pw class window to display the results. What I am trying to do now is get the output printed to my textArea into a .txt file once the displayC method is called. You can see what I tried below, but nothing is happening and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Expected output would be the display and displayC methods both being present on the output before being saved to the file with the build name as the file name in txt format.

Method that prints:

```
package pcbuilder;
    
public class pccalc {

public void display() {
    
    curWatt = cpu + cpuO + mobo + gpu + fastStore + slowStore + store + exStore + fan + sound; ////(http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-consumption-of-pc-components.html) for high end Mobo
    
    System.out.printf("The max PSU wattage estimate is: " + curWatt + ".%n");
    System.out.println("We suggest a minimum of 80+ Gold rating.");
    System.out.println("A wattage of even 100w - 200w less is doable!");
    
}

public void displayC(String n, String cb, String cl, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf) {
    
    curWatt = cpu + cpuO + mobo + gpu + fastStore + slowStore + store + exStore + fan + sound; 
    
    System.out.printf("%nBuild Name: %s", buildName);
    System.out.printf("%nCPU - %s %s: %d", cb, cl, cpu);
    System.out.printf("%nCPU OC Needed: %d", cpuO);
    System.out.printf("%nMotherboard: %d", mobo);
    System.out.printf("%nGPU - %s %s: %d", gb, gl, gpu);
    System.out.printf("%nSSD/NVME - %s: %d", fs, fastStore);
    System.out.printf("%nHDD - %s: %d", ss, slowStore);
    System.out.printf("%nUnused Sata/NVME - %s: %d", sa, store);
    System.out.printf("%nCD/DVD/BlueRay - %s: %d", fq, exStore);
    System.out.printf("%nFans - %s: %d", cf, fan);
    System.out.printf("%nOverhead for Sound: %d", sound);
    System.out.printf("%nTotal Estimated Wattage: %d%n", curWatt);

    }
}
```

Class that displays results in window

```
package pcbuilder;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class pw {

    test nt = new test();
    private JFrame framePU;
    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Your Max PSU Estimate!");
    JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    JTextArea psuArea = new JTextArea();        
    PrintStream printStream = new PrintStream(new CustomOutputStream(psuArea));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    JButton btnAdv = new JButton("Advanced Breakdown");
    pccalc pcp = new pccalc("");

    
    
    String in = "";
    String cbrand = "N/A";
    String cline = "N/A" ;
    String oclock = "";
    String gbrand = "N/A";
    String gline = "N/A";
    String fstorage = "0";
    String sstorage = "0";
    String savailable = "0";
    String fquarter = "0";
    String cfan = "0";
    String soverhead = "";
    String fn = in + ".txt";
    int btnct = 0;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    

    public void newScreen(String n, String cb, String cl, String oc, String gb, String gl, String fs, String ss, String sa, String fq, String cf, String so) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {

                    lblNewLabel.setText("A different label");

                    in = n;
                    cbrand = cb;
                    cline = cl;
                    oclock = oc;
                    gbrand = gb;
                    gline = gl;
                    fstorage = fs;
                    sstorage = ss;
                    savailable = sa;
                    fquarter = fq;
                    cfan = cf;
                    soverhead = so;
                    
                    //A method from the pccalc class that recalculates based on the strings passed through.
                    pcp.reCalc(in, cbrand, cline, oclock, gbrand, gline, fstorage, sstorage, savailable, fquarter, cfan, soverhead);
                    pcp.display();
                    
                    framePU.setVisible(true);
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public pw() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        framePU = new JFrame();
        framePU.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 348);
        framePU.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        framePU.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        
        
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(128, 6, 200, 16);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);
        
        
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(6, 26, 438, 246);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(scrollPane_1);
        
        
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(psuArea);
        
        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                
                if (btnct != 1) {
                    
                    pcp.displayC(in, cbrand, cline, gbrand, gline, fstorage, sstorage, savailable, fquarter, cfan);
                    
                }
                
                PrintStream fileStream = null;
                try {
                    fileStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(in));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                System.setOut(fileStream);

            }
        });
        btnSave.setBounds(45, 284, 86, 29);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(btnSave);
        
        

        btnAdv.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                pcp.displayC(in, cbrand, cline, gbrand, gline, fstorage, sstorage, savailable, fquarter, cfan);
                btnAdv.setEnabled(false);
                btnct++;
            }
        });
        btnAdv.setBounds(214, 284, 187, 29);
        framePU.getContentPane().add(btnAdv);
        
        scrollPane.setBounds(22, 354, 354, 230);
        System.setOut(printStream);
        System.setErr(printStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: *What I am trying to do now is get the output printed to my textArea into a .txt file* - Use the `write(...)` method of the JTextArea. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380 for a working example.

Comment: The only output statements I see go to System.out. You could redirect stdio when you launch your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing output to `System.out` and using `System.setOut` to change what it points to ends up being confusing in the long run. I would suggest passing a `PrintStream` to the `pccalc.display` and `pccalc.displayC` methods so that you don't have to change System.out:

```
public void display(PrintStream out) {
    curWatt = cpu + cpuO + mobo + gpu + fastStore + slowStore + store + exStore + fan + sound; ////(http://www.buildcomputers.net/power-consumption-of-pc-components.html) for high end Mobo
    out.printf("The max PSU wattage estimate is: " + curWatt + ".%n");
    out.println("We suggest a minimum of 80+ Gold rating.");
    out.println("A wattage of even 100w - 200w less is doable!");
}
```

Don't forget to pass in the correct output stream every time you call these methods:

```
pcp.display(printStream);
```

Now writing to new file is easy:

```
try (PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(name of your file here))) {
    pcp.display(fileStream);
    pcp.displayC(fileStream, the rest of your long parameter list here);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    // display an error dialog to the user here
}
```

I would also suggest you give meaningful names to your methods and variables - you'll thank yourself in the long run

Comment: Thank you for the help. I plan on renaming the some of the methods and variables down the road, just want the code to work so when I do my next project I have a better idea of what to do.

Comment: What I am having a hard time understanding is where I make these changes, could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: The changes to the display and displayC methods are done in the "pccalc" class. The new try-catch block replaces the one in your save button action listener: `PrintStream fileStream = null;
                try {
                    fileStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(in));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: Still not saving to text. I wasn't able to get the PrintStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream to work("text.txt:) to work unless I had PrintStream changed to FileOutputStream. Even so still no .txt file is being created.

Comment: Looks like I somehow messed up an edit. The code was supposed to be: `PrintStream fileStream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("name of file"))` If the program runs without errors, the file is being created, but it's possible it's not being created where you think. Try using an absolute path for fhe file, like `c:/file.txt` on windows

Comment: file is being created, but nothing inside of it. I had to comment out the PrintStream fileStream = null; and System.setOut(fileStream) to prevent a "fileStream cannot be resolved" from System.setOut(fileStream). I assume I need to close it somewhere?

Comment: If you use the *"try-with-resources"* statement like I showed, you don't need to close it explicitly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220170/discussion-between-skepticaltiger-and-joni).

Comment: Discussion Chat sent. Not sure where to go from here.