# show the input in a differnet class from a JTextField using IO files

Tags: java, user-interface, io

i have a window that takes info from the user and if there is anything wrong it would show a dialog message but i also want to read the input and show the output from this code using io files
i understand the concept but i failed to link it to this code
any tip would help me
here is the code

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
      String fi =f.getText(); 
      String la = l.getText();
      String ii = i.getText();    
      String ma=m.getText();
      String dob=d.getText();
      String ad= a.getText();
      String ph = p.getText();
      if(fi.equals("") ||  la.equals("")|| ii.equals("")|| ma.equals("") || dob.equals("") || ad.equals("") || ph.equals("")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incomplete Information","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
    else if( !ph.startsWith("05") || ph.trim().length()!=10){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Phone should start with 05 and contains 10 digit","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
    else if( ii.trim().length()!=10){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid ID should be 10 digit","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }
    else if( !dob.trim().matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid date of birth should be YYYY-MM-DD format","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: So...what you want to do is save the data from within the JTextFields into a text file?

Comment: yes and show it again

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880169/loading-a-text-file-into-a-textarea/5887380#5887380 for an example of reading/writing text from/to a text component.